# Is there a way to control inset/offset size?

Tags: inkscape

When using Path>Inset the inset is a big too big? Can I change its size?

And I know about dynamic offset but when I try to do it to multiple objects (which I need in this case) Inkscape just switches to Edit path by nodes and doesn't show the handle to control the inset. However if I try to do it with each object individually I can't find any numerical control to make sure the offset is the same for all objects.

So I guess my question would be how to set identical inset size for multiple objects?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image: inset outset offset]

One word is worth one one-thousandth of a picture.

Third parameter in the right side menu appears to give the flexibility you require.

Comment: The offset is controllable this way, but I'm not sure about the units. I entered an offset in inches and the offset created was 8X what I wanted. Maybe I did it wrong; or maybe there's a bug here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  If you use a Dynamic Offset, you can enter the exact amount of offset in the XML editor.

- Select the object which you already applied the Dynamic Offset to.
- Open the XML editor <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- The `<svg:path id="pathxxxx">` of the object you selected will be highlighted automatically
- Click on the *inkscape:radius* attribute
- In the box underneath, type the value you want, and Press
  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to commit the change.  Note: negative values are inset, positve values are outset.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tend not to use inset and outset. I prefer to group the objects, duplicate the group and click on it then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+drag on the corner handles to scale inplace.

Comment: What you describe is a completely different operation, though.

Comment: Can work if you have a convex shape and do not care about having a uniform inset. But probably the OP wants uniform inset on a general shape.

Answer (score 0):

From Inkscape 1.1 and maybe earlier version you can do the following: group (Ctrl-G) your objects and apply the *Path Effect* called Offset.